# Jboss Netty - Fails to send data continuously?

Tags: java, network-programming, netty

Using JBOSS Netty, I'm trying to send data continuously to the connected client.  In the example below,
I try to send the time every 5 secs to the client, as soon as the client gets connected (channelConnected).

But this is not working.  It works only if I comment the while loop.

```
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    import org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineFactory;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelStateEvent;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.ExceptionEvent;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory;
    import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder;

    public class SRNGServer {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          // Configure the server.
          ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
                  new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                          Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                          Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

          // Configure the pipeline factory.
          bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new SRNGServerPipelineFactoryP());

          // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
          bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8080));
      }



      private static class SRNGServerHandlerP extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SRNGServerHandlerP.class.getName());


        @Override
        public void channelConnected(
                ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
          // Send greeting for a new connection.
          e.getChannel().write("Welcome to " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() + "!\r\n");

          while(true){
            e.getChannel().write("It is " + new Date() + " now.\r\n");

            Thread.sleep(1000*5);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void exceptionCaught(
                ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
            logger.log(
                    Level.WARNING,
                    "Unexpected exception from downstream.",
                    e.getCause());
            e.getChannel().close();
        }
      }



      private static class SRNGServerPipelineFactoryP implements ChannelPipelineFactory {

        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {

            // Create a default pipeline implementation.
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();

            pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
            pipeline.addLast("handler", new SRNGServerHandlerP());

            return pipeline;
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: by not working, what is the result you are getting?

Comment: @Prusswan:Nothing is seen in the output....Output is shown only if the channelConnected method "returns" and whatever's up the stack gets executed, since this is event driven.

Answer (score 3):

The Netty documentation actually states that you should never make a Handler wait because it might eventually deadlock. The reason is that handler methods are called directly by I/O threads. One I/O thread in Netty performs multiple I/O operations in a sequence, so it's not one thread per operation.
In the channelConnected method you should start a new thread with a reference to the channel and make that thread send the time every 5 seconds. This would spawn one thread per connection.
Alternatively, you can have one single thread looping over a list of clients every 5 seconds and sending the time to each of them in a sequence.
Anyway, it's important to use a different thread for sending than the one that calls the Handler.

Comment: I think it should work and here's why: when calling the write method you're adding the write event to Netty's I/O event queue. But it does not fire right away, since you're still in the channelConnected method. Once you're out of it, the write event will fire and when it completes it will call the listener you defined, but in a new thread. It's that new thread that will be sleeping for 5 seconds and not Netty's I/O thread.

Answer (score 2):

For what its worth, I figured the solution and here's the working code.  After the "write" of time, I register the future with my ChannelFuturelistener.  And then from operationComplete I keep registering the new future for every write.  This works for what I want to accomplish, without using any extra threads.

```
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
    import java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    import org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.Channel;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineFactory;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelStateEvent;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.ExceptionEvent;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler;
    import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory;
    import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder;

    public class SRNGServer {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          // Configure the server.
          ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
                  new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                          Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                          //Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
                          Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2),2
                          ));

          // Configure the pipeline factory.
          bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new SRNGServerPipelineFactoryP());

          // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
          bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8080));
      }



      private static class SRNGServerHandlerP extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SRNGServerHandlerP.class.getName());


        @Override
        public void channelConnected(
                ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {

          // Send greeting for a new connection.
          Channel ch=e.getChannel();
          ChannelFuture writeFuture=e.getChannel().write("It is " + new Date() + " now.\r\n");

          SRNGChannelFutureListener srngcfl=new SRNGChannelFutureListener();

          writeFuture.addListener(srngcfl);      

        }

        @Override
        public void exceptionCaught(
                ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {

            logger.log(
                    Level.WARNING,
                    "Unexpected exception from downstream.",
                    e.getCause());
            if(e.getCause() instanceof ClosedChannelException){
              logger.log(Level.INFO, "****** Connection closed by client - Closing Channel");
            }
            e.getChannel().close();
        }
      }



      private static class SRNGServerPipelineFactoryP implements ChannelPipelineFactory {

        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {

            // Create a default pipeline implementation.
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();

            pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
            pipeline.addLast("handler", new SRNGServerHandlerP());

            return pipeline;
        }
      }


      private static class SRNGChannelFutureListener implements ChannelFutureListener{

        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws InterruptedException{
          Thread.sleep(1000*5);
          Channel ch=future.getChannel();
          if(ch!=null && ch.isConnected()){
              ChannelFuture writeFuture=ch.write("It is " + new Date() + " now.\r\n");
              //-- Add this instance as listener itself.
              writeFuture.addListener(this);
          }

        }

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the I/O thread is getting blocked as a result of sleep, so try using 2 worker threads instead:

```
ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
    new NioServerSocketChannelFactory( Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
        Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), 2 ) );
```